# Teamsite template related question

Tags: teamsite

I have a problem with teamsite 6 - I create new category under templatedata with single type
Like categoyX/typeY
TypeY contains datacapture.cfg as well as data and presentation folder (presentation folder has one template)

Now I try to run content creation form but see message: "Unable to create a new form of type categoryX/typeY under the branch ... This form was not configured for this branch or you do not have permission to access it"

I am new to team site - can anybody help with this issue?

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to add an entry to your TEAMSITE_FOLDER/local/config/**templating.cfg**. This file cannot be accessed through the teamsite back-office ; you will have to browse the filesystem.

Add the following node :

```
<templating ...>
  <category name="categoyX">
      ...

      <data-type name="typeY" dcr-type="xml">
        <viewoptions dcr-autonaming="f" actionlist="save;saveas" dcr-renaming="f" />
      </data-type>
  </category>
</templating>
```

Regards